# Remount share folder in VMware workstation

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, shared-folders

I use share folder in VMware workstation,  host Windows 11, guest:Ubuntu.

The problem is the sometime (maybe when I restart the host, the share folder doesn't exist in `/mnt/` so I need to disable and enable the share folder using VMware setting and then the share folder works again.

Is there any simple way ?

Comment: Are the VMware Tools up to date?   Tools are required for the Shared Folder setting to work.  Maybe reinstall the Tools if you can. Menu may be greyed out if up to date.

Comment: Also make sure VMware Workstation is Version 16 or 17 for Windows 11. I am using VMware V17 and have an Ubuntu V22.04 guest (amongst other Guests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the Map as a network drive in windows guests option, all the shared folders in This PC will be displayed as a Map Drive (it is better to activate this option for your convenience)

[image: According to the picture]

If you want to see your folders from inside the virtual machine, just go to This PC and look in the Network Location section.

[image: view pic]

guest:Ubuntu. package requirements may require installing the following tools:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop open-vm-tools
```

A series of friends say that these things are also necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-virtual module-assistant  linux-image-virtual && dpkg-reconfigure open-vm-tools
```

If you don't see your shared folders (automounted) inside /mnt/hgfs , run VMware configuration tools:

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs
```

and run:`vmware-hgfsclient` then view /mnt content with  `ll /mnt/`

And finally

Make sure the `/mnt/hgfs` directory exists and update your **fstab** using the details below, If not, create it.

Add the following line to `nano /etc/fstab`:

```
vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs  fuse defaults,allow_other   0   0
```